# Storing a pointer to a template type of the same template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Let's say we have the following:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class Foo {
private:
    A m_a;
    B m_b;
    Foo<A,B>* m_pFoo;

public:
    Foo( A a, B b, Foo<A,B>* pFoo = nullptr );
};
```

With this class I can save any `pFoo` into `m_pFoo` as long as the instantiation
of types match as such:

```
 int main() {
     Foo<int, int> foo1( 3, 5 );
     Foo<int, int> foo2( 2, 4, &foo1 ); // This Works
     Foo<int, int> foo3( 5, 7, &foo2 ); // This Still Works 

     Foo<double, int> foo4( 2.4, 5 );
     Foo<double, int> foo5( 7.5, 2, &foo4 ); // This Works
     Foo<double, int> foo6( 9.2, 6, &foo5 ); // This Still Works

     // Compiler Error - Can not deduce template arguments
     Foo<double, int> foo7( 3.7, 2, &foo1 ); // Doesn't Work

     return 0;
 }
```

In a previous question I demonstrated a similar problem as this and my initial question was how to pass a pointer to a class template type into the same class template constructor, however one of the responses I received regarding this was that passing in the pointer is not the problem, but the storage is. So with this post my new question becomes this:

How would I be able to have the same class template with the same or similar constructor as above where each of these types:

```
Foo<short, short>           ssFoo;
Foo<short, int>             siFoo;
Foo<short, int64_t>         si64Foo;
Foo<short, unsigned>        suFoo;
Foo<short, float>           sfFoo;
Foo<short, double>          sdFoo;
Foo<short, long>            slFoo;
Foo<short, long long>       sllFoo;

Foo<int, short>             isFoo;
Foo<int, int>               iiFoo;
Foo<int, int64_t>           ii64Foo;
Foo<int, unsigned>          iuFoo;
Foo<int, float>             ifFoo;
Foo<int, double>            idFoo;
Foo<int, long>              ilFoo;
Foo<int, long long>         illFoo;

Foo<int64_t, short>        i64sFoo;
Foo<int64_t, int>          i64iFoo;
Foo<int64_t, int64_t>      i64i64Foo;
Foo<int64_t, unsigned>     i64uFoo;
Foo<int64_t, float>        i64fFoo;
Foo<int64_t, double>       i64dFoo;
Foo<int64_t, long>         i64lFoo;
Foo<int64_t, long long>    i64llFoo;

Foo<unsigned, short>        usFoo;
Foo<unsigned, int>          uiFoo;
Foo<unsigned, int64_t>      ui64Foo;
Foo<unsigned, unsigned>     uuFoo;
Foo<unsigned, float>        ufFoo;
Foo<unsigned, double>       udFoo;
Foo<unsigned, long>         ulFoo;
Foo<unsigned, long long>    ullFoo;

Foo<float, short>           fsFoo;
Foo<float, int>             fiFoo;
Foo<float, int64_t>         fi64Foo;
Foo<float, unsigned>        fuFoo;
Foo<float, float>           ffFoo;
Foo<float, double>          fdFoo;
Foo<float, long>            flFoo;
Foo<float, long long>       fllFoo;

Foo<double, short>          dsFoo;
Foo<double, int>            diFoo;
Foo<double, int64_t>        di64Foo;
Foo<double, unsigned>       duFoo;
Foo<double, float>          dfFoo;
Foo<double, double>         ddFoo;
Foo<double, long>           dlFoo;
Foo<double, long long>      dllFoo;

Foo<long, short>            lsFoo;
Foo<long, int>              liFoo;
Foo<long, int64_t>          li64Foo;
Foo<long, unsigned>         luFoo;
Foo<long, float>            lfFoo;
Foo<long, double>           ldFoo;
Foo<long, long>             llFoo;
Foo<long, long long>        l_llFoo;

Foo<long long, short>       llsFoo;
Foo<long long, int>         lliFoo;
Foo<long long, int64_t>     lli64Foo;
Foo<long long, unsigned>    lluFoo;
Foo<long long, float>       llfFoo;
Foo<long long, double>      lldFoo;
Foo<long long, long>        ll_lFoo;
Foo<long long, long long>   ll_llFoo;
```

Are all valid types to store within the class template upon construction where the address of the previous instance is being passed into the new instance's constructor? Also; how would I be able to prevent this class from accepting anything that is a custom or user defined object or character, string types, enumerations and Boolean types? I would like the `typenames` being passed into the class templates argument list as being numerical types only.

Comment: Despite all being named `Foo`, they're all different types. If you want to make a polymorphic base class of `Foo`, you might be able to achieve what you want, depending on how much of the class's traits are dependent on the template parameters. I don't think there's a type safe way to arbitrarily store any object inside the class and remember what it was. Restricting the types is easy enough with `<type_traits>` and `static_assert`, though.

Comment: You have failed to say what you want to do with these pointers.  So a wuick test if the types match, change the pointer to a `void*`, and done.  Useless, because you can do nearly nothing with a `void*`, but you did not ask "and then do something with it": you just asked to store it.  Probaly this is an XY problem.  Or maybe you do want to store a `void*` and do nothing with it.

Comment: I know they are different types; that isn't the issue. I was trying to figure out how to be able to save different types. I understand that `<int,int>` is different from `<int, float>` and `<double, unsigned>`. The class being a class template prevents me from having to write the same class 30 - 50 times for each different type, and any of these types are valid for the last parameter. The issue was storing a pointer to any valid type that this class template can generate and saving them within the instance of the class who's constructor's pointer isn't `nullptr`.

Comment: @Yakk consider this mathematics dealing with polynomials: a polynomial has terms for example: 2x, 3, 5x^2, 3x^4*2y^5 are all single terms to a polynomial. The two typenames for the term are <Coefficient, Exponent> this is why either of them can be any numerical type only. Consider this term  3x^(5x^2) this is still a single term; and so is x^(2x^(2y^3)) . So in my original source of 3x^(5x^2): `Term<int,int> termExpression( 5, 'x', 2, /*nullptr*/ );` `Term<int, int> term( 3, 'x', 1, &termExpression );`. If the stored pointer is null then term is complete, ...

Comment: @Yakk (...continued) otherwise the pointer is another term that is part of the current terms exponent. I want the ability to be able to express this:  3.2x^(2x^4.5)   so this in code would be: `Term<unsigned, double> expression( 2, 'x', 4.5 );`  `Term<float, int> term( 3.2f, 'x', 1, &expression );` Here is a link to my original question with the actual class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621908/passing-a-pointer-to-a-template-class-into-the-same-template-classs-constructor

Comment: That is all well and good, but I don't care.  I care what you eant to *do* to these pointed-to objects.  If the answer is "everything, easily", then tough luck.  If it is nothing, easy.  If it is something in between, then you have not expressed it.

Comment: @Yakk for now, just displaying it as a mathematical expression. Later on the class itself will have defined operators to do basic arithmetic on two terms along with comparison functions. I may define a reducing and factor function as well.

Answer (score 3):

An instance of a template is a completely distinct type, separate from all other types, and other instances of the template.

```
Foo<short, short>
```

and

```
Foo<int, int>
```

are two different classes, which are just as different from each other as

```
Foo1;
```

and

```
Foo2;
```

are different from each other.

These are different classes. It follows that:

```
Foo<short, short> *m_pFoo;
```

and

```
Foo<int, int> *m_pFoo;
```

are also as different from each other as

```
Foo1 *m_pFoo;
```

and

```
Foo2 *m_pFoo;
```

are. C++ just doesn't work this way. The `m_pFoo` member of your template can only point to one class. You have to pick which one it is. It could be the same type as its own class, that's one option. Or, it can point to an instance of some other class. But it can only be one class.

Unless, of course, you make it a

```
void *m_pFoo;
```

But, you'll lose type safety and type checking, of course, going that route.

As it's been mentioned in the comments, you might be able to derive the template from a superclass, and store a pointer to the superclass:

```
class FooBase {

// ...

};

template<typename A, typename B> class Foo : public FooBase {

    A m_a;
    B m_b;
    FooBase* m_pFoo;

public:
    Foo( A a, B b, FooBase* pFoo = nullptr );
};
```

So, you'll be able to pass a pointer to any `Foo<A, B>` to the constructor, which will be automatically casted to the superclass, and only the pointer to the superclass will get stored.

This approach, of course, has many other implications, but this would be the cleanest, most type-safe approach -- at least up to this point -- that I can think of.

Comment: If we knew what the OP wanted to do, exactly, with the data, type erasure is another option (instead of inheritance).  It lets you create an ad-hoc interface for unrelated types.

Comment: @Yakk here is a link to my original question with the actual class that I was using. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621908/passing-a-pointer-to-a-template-class-into-the-same-template-classs-constructor

Comment: @francis if you only want to display, then throw out all that junk and store a string.  Again, what you want to do matters to the ideal solution.  Failure to describe what you want to do *after you store them*, even roughly, means people are stuck guessing.  And asking for the moon will also give you bad answers.

Answer (score 1):

Let's address the compiler error and why it's happening first: 
The reason the template arguments can't be deduced is because the constructor accepts a pointer to type `Foo<A, B>`. When you define foo7, you have made a foo7 of type `Foo<double, int>`. You then attempt to pass a reference to foo1 to its parameter which is of type `Foo<int, int>` but the constructor expects a `Foo<double, int>`.

To deal with this, one could create a third template type to be able to take in any other kind of `Foo` while not being restricted to the current type being constructed. I apologize if this isn't worded very well. I wrote an example:

```
template<typename A, typename... Rest>
class Foo;

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Foo<A, B, C>{
private:
    A m_a;
    B m_b;
    C* m_pFoo;

public:
    Foo(A a, B b, C* p_Foo);
};

template<typename A, typename B>
class Foo<A, B>{
private:
    A m_a;
    B m_b;
    Foo<A, B>* m_pFoo;

public:
    Foo(A a, B b, Foo<A, B>* p_Foo = nullptr);
};
```

Here, we've declared a class, Foo, that can take 1 or more template arguments. Following this, there's a definition for a Foo that takes three template arguments, and a Foo that takes only two template arguments.
With the three-argument definition, we have a third type which will be the type of the m_pFoo pointer. In the two-argument definition we declare m_pFoo to be of type `Foo<A, B>*` (this is the initial behavior of your original code)

```
int main() {
    Foo<int, int> foo1(3, 5);
    Foo<int, int, decltype(foo1)> foo2(2, 4, &foo1); 
    Foo<int, int, decltype(foo2)> foo3(5, 7, &foo2); 

    Foo<double, int> foo4(2.4, 5);
    Foo<double, int, decltype(foo4)> foo5(7.5, 2, &foo4);
    Foo<double, int, decltype(foo5)> foo6(9.2, 6, &foo5); 

    //Now works.
    Foo<double, int, decltype(foo1)> foo7(3.7, 2, &foo1); 

    return 0;
}
```

Now we can pass in the type of the foo instance as a template argument using decltype (added in C++11).

It's not 'automatic' and still requires you to explicitly state the type of the foo you want to pass to the constructor, but I think this should be pretty close to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm using VS2015 CE on Win7 64bit, and I'm following your structure and can not get it to compile.

Comment: These and a few more: 1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\stackoverflowsolutions\readintegers\storage.h(114): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\stackoverflowsolutions\readintegers\storage.h(114): error C2059: syntax error: '<end Parse>'
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\stackoverflowsolutions\readintegers\storage.inl(30): error C2039: '{ctor}': is not a member of 'Foo<A,B,C>'

Comment: However when I add the key word `class` before the class name in its first declaration; I do not get these errors.

Comment: After fixing that everything seems to compile now; but I'll have to run some tests with my class's functions.

Comment: Oh, yes, the class keyword needs to be there. I had copied it directly from my editor but somehow deleted it when formatting it for the SO code block. Whoops. I'll edit the answer to fix that.

Comment: The only problem them I'm getting now is that if I try to reference the pointer from one instance who has accepted another, I can not access the pointer because it is a private member. I'll either have to create an access function, or to design both classes to be a friend of each other and make the data protected.